# Simplifying the code to avoid TLE while rotating 2D matrix clockwise

Tags: c++

I have working code for rotating 2D matrix in clockwise direction but I'm having TLE (time  limit exceeded) problem when `k` reaches big numbers. I don't know how to simplify my code, I'm guessing the for cycles are causing the problem but I can't see a way to make my code work without them. Is there any other way to simplify my code to avoid TLE?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
void funk(int a[][101], int n,int k);

int main()
{
    int a[101][101],n,k;
    ifstream ived;
    ived.open("15.txt");
    ived>>n>>k;
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        for (int j=0; j<n; j++) {
            ived>>a[i][j];
      }
    }
    ived.close();
    funk(a, n, k);
    ofstream isved;
    isved.open("15rez.txt");
    for (int i=0;i<n; i++) {
        for (int j=0; j<n; j++) {
            isved<<a[i][j]<<" ";
        }
    isved<<endl;
    }
    isved.close();
  return 0;
}


void funk(int a[][101], int n, int k) {

    for (int pak=0; pak<k; pak++) {
        for (int i=0; i<n/2; i++) {
            for (int j=i; j<n-i-1; j++) {
                int prad=a[i][j];
                a[i][j] = a[n-1-j][i];
                a[n-1-j][i] = a[n-1-i][n-1-j];
                a[n-1-i][n-1-j] = a[j][n-1-i];
              a[j][n-1-i]=prad;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `k` is the number of times the matrix should be rotated, then you can use the fact that after 4 rotations it transforms into itself. Hence, the result will be the same if you replace `k` with `k % 4`, thereby replacing `O(k)` algorithm with `O(1)` one.